# How to create a isometric drag & drop Grid with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make a isometric drag & drop Grid to drag objects onto the grid with JavaScript?

I started using WebGL (Three.js) but it's not a good solution (not really responsive for my purposes). So now I think about doing it with HTML Elements.

The grid looks likes this (just an image at the end too)

[image: Isometric Grid]
Now I just wanna get some ways (no code, just ideas) how to realize it:

- Grid as image (like the attached one)
- Drag Objects from a Sidebar into it (1*1, 2*2, 3*3, .. tiles large)
- Not possible to drop two overlapping objects on the same tile

Which ways are possible to do it? It should be usable on mobile devices also.

Comment: You're likely going to need some non-image representation of the grid... if you use a grid of html elements you could use css transforms to position the html-grid like the image, and then you would have access to click and hover events, making drag-and-drop fairly simple. Otherwise you're going to need to mathematically transform cursor coordinates to grid coordinates (based on the rotation/scaling of the image) which may not be entirely precise.

Comment: @GershomMaes The problem is, every object is just an image, even the grid is an image (it's from a game..). The images are already isometric (like the grid) but I started using jquery ui (draggable) but maybe its easier to create it by my own. I'll just need a responsive solutions so it's hard to do it purely with css.

Comment: I would personally avoid using the image for the grid. If your game is going to rely on interacting with the grid css and html is likely the way to go - that way you can colour tiles differently, detect clicks, etc.

Comment: It's just a game map overview and builder, it would'nt get to be a game. The tiles are just grass (images) and I didn't even need to color them anytime. All the images are there already (sprites). So I just found phaser.js, maybe this is a good way or did u (or anyone else) knows any better solution?

Comment: gershom maes is good advice, you may play with an old codepen of mine here : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/HdpAI  use your sprites as background ;) skew it as much you like ;)

Answer (score 8):

Of course you shouldn't expect a full answer to this question! But here's something to get you started (in the direction that I personally feel would be the most productive).

Here's your grid, but in html/css, which means you can now interact with it easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/kqs0gq78/

It's a simple html/css grid; took advantage of the `transform` property to get the 3d effect. The grid could be arbitrarily resized; right now there are 10 rows/cols, the grid is 100x100, therefore each cell is 10x10. If you decide you need many more cells you may want to generate the html with javascript. You'll need to change the css values beyond 100x100 sizing if you add more cells.

You can now detect clicks on certain tiles as you normally would with javascript, begin to check for hover events (which means that the user has dragged the tile), and finally once the user releases the click that will indicate the end of the drag operation.

Hope this is useful! :)

```css
.wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.wrapper:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.wrapper > .grid {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.grid > .row {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.grid > .row > .cell {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.grid > .row > .cell:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
.grid {
  transform: rotateX(40deg) rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
      <div class="cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice example dude, and no I don't except a full answer (also don't except any code). This is awesome, but I don't need help in creating a isometric CSS grid, I need some Ideas to use a image as grid and display other images on it (isometric tiles) with drag & drop ability. But this is a nice start too.

Comment: Late reply but - you could just stick that image on as the background...

Comment: No problem thank you, yeah that's an option! But some buildings (let's call them buildings) are images that stick on 4*4 tiles or 3*3 tiles. I'll play around with it soon again :-)

Comment: many years later... have you found/developed something? I'm also looking for a simple 2D isometric type of block management. with three.js you may be able to build it in 3D : https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_interactive_voxelpainter

Comment: or this : https://jdan.github.io/isomer/